# Salesforce Hybrid Android App

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, android

I have created hybrid android app with salesforce mobile sdk. However the lookup functionality of salesforce is not working.

In the app if i click the Accounts lookup a new page is opened where i can search for the accounts but the problem is when i select the desired account to add in the lookup it is not taking me to the previous page and populate the Account name which i have selected.

Has anyone faced a problem like this before?  If so is there any work around?